# module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.3

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

I'm pretty new to scala and I need to sumbit my code to spark. I already tried to compress my code to a .jar trough Eclipse but I've got many dependencies so it doesn't work well.. So after some research I found sbt with the assembly plugin. I installed sbt (default version in apt-get 1.0.4) and made this organisation in my folders :

```
- RootFolder
    -- bin
    -- project
        --- assembly.sbt
        --- build.properties 
    -- src
        --- scala
            ---- BloomFilter.scala
            ---- TestCRA.scala
    -- target
    -- buildt.sbt
```

So in my **build.sbt** :

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

in my **assembly.sbt** :

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")
```

and in my **build.properties** :

```
sbt.version=1.0.4
```

So when I launch : `$ sbt assembly` in my RootProject I've got this :

```
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.2
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/quentin/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.2/sbt-assembly-0.14.2.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/quentin/.sbt/preloaded/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/0.14.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/quentin/.sbt/preloaded/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.2/sbt-assembly-0.14.2.pom
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar) (500ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/quentin/Documents/Eclipse/BloomFilters/project/assembly.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:bloomfilters-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.2: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2356)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.2: not found
```

Actually I made a lot of research and I'm totally tied. I've read a lot of stackoverflow topics about this and I know there's a lot on this issue but I would'nt write this if I didn't tried them all.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my language.

Quentin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[It seems](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/releases) ("sbt-assembly 0.14.5 is cross built to sbt 0.13 and 1.x.") currently only sbt-assembly 0.14.5 and 0.14.6 are supporting sbt 1.x. So you have to update to that:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

Comment: thank you a lot.. Indeed I tried every version I found on dl.bintray but not the 0.14.6 ! So my jar is made but it seems my .scala aren't in my jar. I tried this : $java -cp Test-assembly-1.0.jar scala.TestCRA and it doesn't work.

Comment: It should not (unless you added that to the `scala` package which is not recommended). It should be called `TestCRA` in case you use the default package.

Comment: Indeed my code was in `scala` package I moved it in a default package and tried with `TestCRA` and it doesn't work einther...

Comment: I must put my scala files in the rep :  src/main/java/ then they will be complied ! Don't forget to add libdependencies in `build.sbt`

Comment: (I think it is better put the scala files to the `src/main/scala` folder, not to `src/main/java`.)