# IntelliJ and sbt sync/other functions suddenly stopped working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Recently and for no apparent reason, my scala code has filled with errors. I do not believe I have altered the code in any way since the last time it worked so I'm very confused. I am working in IntelliJ and whenever I open the project or try to build it, I get

```
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

This results in IntelliJ reporting a failed sync for this project as well as it marking any sbt related statements in the build.sbt file as being errors. In the end I am trying to package this code into a .jar file, as I have before, but even if I try to do that from the command line, I get the same issues.

Here is the build.sbt file displaying all the errors that used to run fine

[image: Errors in build.sbt]

Here are the full logs:
https://pastebin.com/Gwp3ddpf

Comment: Does it build/run from the command line? Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I added the log error above. It seems to be something with Kotlin

Comment: It's not clear if this error is relevant to the problem you have. You should share the full log via a service like pastebin or dropbox. Also make sure that the project builds from the command line, outside of the IDE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm not necessarily sure what it means to build it from the command line. I'm working with Apache Spark so I usually either spark-submit the .jar or run it in spark-shell, which currently works

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project

Comment: @CrazyCoder It does not compile, I still get the same error relating to the unresolved dependency

Comment: You have to share the full log as requested, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's the issue.

Comment: Just added the full logs

Comment: SBT is not able to resolve the dependency for some reason: `com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=1.0)`.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, but a lot of the other solutions I've seen online haven't helped

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788890/104891)?

Comment: I did, it does nothing but change the .0 to a .6 in the errors

Comment: Sorry, I have no ideas, maybe someone else will provide a solution.

Comment: With some recent update, the IntelliJ scala plugin started to used the latest sbt version by default instead of what is configured in the project. Thus, if you have recently updated IntelliJ, it might be that the sbt version used in the sbt console is newer than what you have configured in your `project/build.properties`. The sbt version override can be disabled in the project sbt settings. Don't know if that's your problem, but why not give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not getting to the repo anymore.  I dunno why but maybe you can force it by adding to `plugins.sbt` in the same directory add

```
resolvers += "Bintray sbt plugin releases"
  at "http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

You can see there is no version 0.14.0 for 2.11 by checking the plugin-in repo. 
http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/