# Which version of Sbt and Sbt assembly to use for Spack 2.4.5 and Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

Currently, in AWS EMR Cluster, I am using Spark `v2.4.5` which comes with Scala `v2.11`. So in my project, I want to use Scala v2.11 and corresponding `SBT` and `Sbt-Assembly` versions. But I am getting one or the other Version conflicts with all the permutations available on various blogs and Stackoverflow answers.

Here is my dependency files which throws error:

build.sbt

```
name := "user-view-services"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
autoScalaLibrary := false

// Major Libraries version
val sparkVersion = "2.4.5"
val kafkaVersion = "2.5.0"
val akkaVersion = "2.6.4"

val confluentRepo = "confluent-repo" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.13" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.0",
  "com.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "5.1",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.9.2",
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.4",
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils-bean-collections" % "1.8.3",
  "org.drools" % "drools-compiler" % "7.41.0.Final",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging_2.11" % "3.5.0"
)

lazy val mongoDBDependencies = Seq(
  "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-sync" % "4.0.2"
)

lazy val akkaDependencies = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion
)

lazy val kafkaDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % kafkaVersion,
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % kafkaVersion,
  "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "5.4.1"
)

lazy val sparkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
)

lazy val rulemodule = (project in file("rule-module"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "rule-module",
    version := "1.0",
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )
/**
 * to create uberjar - run command
 * 1) sbt "sparkjobs / clean"
 * 2) sbt "sparkjobs / assembly"
 */
lazy val sparkjobs = (project in file("user-enrich-batch"))
  .dependsOn(rulemodule)
  .settings(
    name := "user-enrich-batch",
    version := "1.0",
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      confluentRepo
    ),
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= kafkaDependencies,
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7",
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    },
    mainClass in assembly := some("com.analytics.user.etl.ETLProcessor"),
    assemblyJarName := "user-view-batch-assembly.jar"
  )

lazy val userservice = (project in file("user-enrich-service"))
  .dependsOn(rulemodule)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "user-enrich-service",
    version := "1.0",
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      confluentRepo
    ),
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= kafkaDependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= akkaDependencies,
    libraryDependencies ++= mongoDBDependencies
  )
```

build.properties

```
sbt.version = 0.13.17
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.4")

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.cavorite" % "sbt-avro-1-9" % "1.1.7")
```

assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

Error:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\smishra5\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dataanalytics\Recsys\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/dataanalytics/Recsys/project/}recsys-build...
[info] Resolving com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.14.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.14.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.ivy2\local\com.eed3si9n\sbt-assembly\scala_2.11\sbt_0.13\0.14.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_0.13/0.14.6/sbt-assembly-0.14.6.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.sbt\preloaded\com.eed3si9n\sbt-assembly\0.14.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/smishra5/.sbt/preloaded/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_0.13/0.14.6/sbt-assembly-0.14.6.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/1.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-native-packager\scala_2.11\sbt_0.13\1.3.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.11_0.13/1.3.4/sbt-native-packager-1.3.4.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.sbt\preloaded\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-native-packager\1.3.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/smishra5/.sbt/preloaded/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.11_0.13/1.3.4/sbt-native-packager-1.3.4.pom
[info] Resolving com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.cavorite/sbt-avro-1-9/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/1.1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.cavorite/sbt-avro-1-9/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/1.1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.ivy2\local\com.cavorite\sbt-avro-1-9\scala_2.11\sbt_0.13\1.1.7\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cavorite/sbt-avro-1-9_2.11_0.13/1.1.7/sbt-avro-1-9-1.1.7.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\smishra5\.sbt\preloaded\com.cavorite\sbt-avro-1-9\1.1.7\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/smishra5/.sbt/preloaded/com/cavorite/sbt-avro-1-9_2.11_0.13/1.1.7/sbt-avro-1-9-1.1.7.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4: not found
[warn]  :: com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.4 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]          com.cavorite:sbt-avro-1-9:1.1.7 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\dataanalytics\Recsys\project\plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]            +- default:recsys-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.4 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\dataanalytics\Recsys\project\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:recsys-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]          com.cavorite:sbt-avro-1-9:1.1.7 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\dataanalytics\Recsys\project\plugins.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]            +- default:recsys-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4: not found
unresolved dependency: com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:320)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1555)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1551)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$122.apply(Defaults.scala:1586)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$122.apply(Defaults.scala:1584)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1589)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1583)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1606)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1533)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1485)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Reference: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/311

Comment: it seems to have a problem with sbt assembly plugin version please look into this: `https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/245` and this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788640/module-not-found-com-eed3si9nsbt-assembly0-14-3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788640/module-not-found-com-eed3si9nsbt-assembly0-14-3)

Comment: Tried to use sbt-assembly;0.14.6 and 0.14.0 with either sbt version 0.13.13 or 1.0.0 or 1.0.4 and it failed in all these permutations with same below error:

unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found

[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4: not found

[error] unresolved dependency: com.cavorite#sbt-avro-1-9;1.1.7: not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're mixing up the Scala version used by SBT and Scala version used in your project.

If you need to build project with Scala 2.11, it's just enough to specify in `build.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

You have to remove `scalaVersion := "2.11.12"` from `plugins.sbt` in the `project` folder as SBT is pre-built with specific Scala version and you cannot change it. For example, `0.13.17` is built with Scala 2.10 and SBT `1.x.x` with Scala `2.12`.

You're free to use any SBT version you like but I'd suggest to use the latest `1.3.13` and latest versions of corresponding plugins.

Comment: Worked after changing "sbt-assembly" version to "0.14.10" and also removing scalaVersion from plugins.sbt Was wondering if there is any relation between the Scala version I want to build my project with i.e. Scala 2.11.12 and the SBT version I am using i.e. Sbt 0.13.13 and the sbt-assembly version i.e. 0.14.10

Comment: @sunny_dev As you probably already understood, the version of Scala used by sbt built is independent from version you're using in the project. As for SBT plugins, they are cross built for different SBT versions (and Scala versions), you can see versions of sbt-assembly plugin that work with sbt 0.13 at [bintray](https://dl.bintray.com/eed3si9n/sbt-plugins/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/)